# Repaint time from 0 to 8ms, Chrome still not scrolling smoothly

Tags: html, performance, css, google-chrome, smooth-scrolling

First of all, let me explain what I mean by "smooth scrolling" here. When I rotate the mouse wheel by one "step", e.g. on Google Search results page, the page gradually moves up/down - the transition from the "before scroll" to "after scroll" states takes some time and is nicely animated. However, whenever I create a long page in html and try to scroll just one "step", there is no animation or transition on scroll - the page just instantly jumps few lines up or down. The average repaint time of my page takes about 5ms, with peaks up to 8ms, so I know repaint time is not the cause of that.
I know that such smooth scrolling can be achieved without any scripting, as for example the site http://www.thecssninja.com/ scrolls super-smooth on Chrome even with js disabled.
Why does Chrome choose not to scroll my page smoothly?  How do I achieve smooth scroll without depending on JS, as CSS Ninja manages to?

PS Firefox does not seem to have that issue. How do I tell Chrome with my html/css that I'd like my page to scroll smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're not after JS solutions, but I've never seen anything guarantee this outside of JavaScript, and karan's link above is certainly the smoothest example I've seen of doing this.

(Proviso: I'm using Chrome for Windows, not Linux.  Apparently, that may make a difference.)

I use Chrome myself, and I always get the pages scrolling in jumps, not smoothly--even the pages you described as 'smooth' above step for me several lines at a time, including the Google results page.  There used to be a flag available for this in Chrome, which allowed you to turn on smooth scrolling -- it could be accessed through Chrome's flags (go to chrome://flags/ to see those that are available) -- but it's now only available for the Linux Chrome platform.  It may be available again in the future, but for now at least, it isn't.  Hopefully, though, these experimental features will eventually find their way into Chrome, and render this whole issue obsolete.

Firefox, on the other hand, scrolls in nice smooth steps no matter what page I'm on--including my own local info pages which have almost no styling at all.  IE scrolls smoothly, though not nearly as nicely as Firefox, while Opera behaves like Chrome, and steps through the pages several lines at a time.

I'm pretty sure that this is an issue to do with the browser, and not something that you can currently remedy with styling alone.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but if you're doing this for a client, at least you'll be able to explain the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Either you can enable chrome smooth scrolling [manually](https://plus.google.com/+RobertKoritnik/posts/9rCL4QwMbqf), which does not make sense for website development.

Or you can use some of the libraries to achieve that.

https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/jquery.smoothwheel

Sadly for chrome you cannot enable smooth scrolling through HTML, CSS or JS.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not interested in JS solutions, as I've seen websites that scroll smooth on my Chrome, even with JS disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend finding an alternate solution, but I have managed to find a solution to this exact problem for one of my websites. Akin to just using glitter glue to solve a leak in a wall, I discovered that including an iframe for a Google map on the page (even if it's hidden) somehow added in smooth scrolling. I have no idea how it works, but for some bizarre reason it does.

As I said though, I highly recommend not doing this, as its an extra (and sometimes lengthy) request made on each page to include an element most users won't ever see.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It further ensures me that this whole case is just caused by a bug in Google Chrome. Shoud've been more careful with that bounty :) But at least now I know

Comment: Could you provide a code sample that makes your website scroll smooth? I"d be glad to check it out, anyway